# Evaluating expression 'failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1) in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to evalute below list items,

```
expected_dataItem = [
'"reference":"dacq/ce7cece3-fb3f-4397-b2aa-cda4761322da/57c9b247-cae6-48e4-9a4e-cf56846ad1e9/2","value":1.0',
'"reference":"dacq/ce7cece3-fb3f-4397-b2aa-cda4761322da/57c9b247-cae6-48e4-9a4e-cf56846ad1e9/1","value":"HelloWorld!!"',
'"reference":"dacq/ce7cece3-fb3f-4397-b2aa-cda4761322da/59cfaccb-1495-4259-8e85-c2d9728d286a","value":1',
'"reference":"dacq/ce7cece3-fb3f-4397-b2aa-cda4761322da/57c9b247-cae6-48e4-9a4e-cf56846ad1e9/1","value":"This is a test."'
```

]

I'm refering to each item based on index value ${expected_dataItem}[0],but I get this error "Evaluating expression 'failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (, line 1) " when I use the builin robotkeyword as below

```
${length}    Get Length     ${expected_dataItem}    
FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${length}
    ${expectedValue}    Evaluate    ${expectedValues_str}[${index}]
    List Should Contain Value    ${container}    ${expectedValue}
END
```

Some suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Change the line "${expectedValue}    Evaluate    ${expectedValues_str}[${index}]" to "${expectedValue}    Set Variable   ${expectedValues_str}[${index}]. I'm almost sure that when using evaluate you need to have a expression to evaluate like "A > B"

Comment: Thanks .But It didn't work. So I used Created list using Create List Robert keyword and It works.